# Disk / Data read increase after putting on an index

Tags: performance, oracle, indexing, execution-time

I have a small query that runs pretty fast.  And somehow I thought adding an index to an unindexed collumn would make it faster but turned out it didn't.  In fact, it does increase my disk reads and execution time.  What I'd like to ask is can someone explain me a detailed info about how the index works and why it could decrease performance rather than increase it.

Thanks in advance!

PS : My RDBMS : Oracle

Comment: This isn't really a programming question; it's more of a DBA question (about administering your database). Voting to migrate it to [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com), where it's more appropriate.

Comment: @Ken White: I disagree.  This is a question about data structures and algorithms.  Some people may have a DBA deal with anything related to indexes, but that doesn't mean this isn't a programming question.

Comment: @jonearles: Sorry, I don't agree. This is a question about database administration (how indexes work, how to properly use them, how indexes can affect performance). It's not about "how do I write code to implement a fast lookup to this data structure?". Unless you have access to the internals of Oracle indexes and data structures, that is, and the question specifically asks about those internals. I don't see that here. Even if the programmer is doing the DBA work, it's still DBA work. :-)

Comment: So am I in the wrong place? Sorry if I put this in wrong place, guys :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entirely possible on a small table.  If the table is truly small it could be that the table can be read entirely into memory with a single read, and a full table scan can be performed entirely in memory.  Adding an index here would require reading at least a single index page, followed by reading the data page, for a doubling of the I/O's.  This is an unusual case but not unheard of.

However, this is just guesswork on my part.  To truly find out what's going on grab the execution plan for your query with the index on, drop the index, and grab the execution plan without the index.  Compare the plans, and decide if you want to re-add the index.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: From what I gather, when I'm using the index the cost is reduced by 1 ( actual cost 9 to 8 ) because of the table access full scan was replaced by the index. But that doesn't mean the index is suitable for this fast query right?

Comment: Oh yeah and in another query case I'm also doing the index placement, If the disk/data read and buffer gets is reduced from the actual state ( before putting the index ) then I can assume that the index is doing its job as it should, right?

Comment: I've found that the best thing to look at is execution time.  :-)  Your logic sounds right to me.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I would If I can but it's somehow difficult to check from the execution time because of the network traffic. So I just want to make sure myself that my index was put at the right place which in return it somehow will have a reduced to the execution time (based from the buffer gets and data/disk reads decrease). Right?

Comment: If adding the index reduces runtime, that's great.  However, if it doesn't reduce runtime then IMO it doesn't matter if it's being used or not - I'd get rid of the index if it doesn't reduce runtime.  I agree that many factors can affect performance, but that's why in a case like this I'll re-run the query many times at many times of the day to get a feel for how it truly performs.

Comment: well what If I get into conclusion that If the buffer gets and data / disk reads reduced then eventually the execution time supposed to be reduced too (fewer reads / buffer gets mean fewer time needed to execute it).  Is my statement acceptable?

Comment: That certainly sounds correct to me.

Comment: well alright sir.  Thank You for being a good help!